How to create in ggplot separate plots for every subject from a study
I have data from crossover study for which I need to plot some graphs.
No problem to draw an 'average' plot for all subjects, but I also need separate plots for every subject with two treatements overlaid (T vs R). And another question - how to assign a subject ID to every plot. Below is a data for 4 subjects (may be more, up to 100).
Totalplot <- 
structure(list(subj = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), seq = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), prd = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
    time = c(0, 0.333, 0.667, 1, 1.333, 1.667, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 
    4, 6, 8, 12, 24, 48, 0, 0.333, 0.667, 1, 1.333, 1.667, 2, 
    2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24, 48, 0, 0.333, 0.667, 1, 1.333, 
    1.667, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24, 48, 0, 0.333, 0.667, 
    1, 1.333, 1.667, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24, 48, 0, 
    0.333, 0.667, 1, 1.333, 1.667, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 6, 8, 12, 
    24, 48, 0, 0.333, 0.667, 1, 1.333, 1.667, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 
    4, 6, 8, 12, 24, 48, 0, 0.333, 0.667, 1, 1.333, 1.667, 2, 
    2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24, 48, 0, 0.333, 0.667, 1, 1.333, 
    1.667, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24, 48), conc = c(0, 
    0, 103.041, 301.731, 371.722, 341.099, 326.791, 279.52, 262.657, 
    234.926, 220.389, 141.804, 112.702, 68.981, 31.9, NA, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 11, 24.436, 57.257, 122.065, 159.702, 271.629, 402.88, 
    154.535, 126.576, 75.999, 33.272, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25.932, 
    134.108, 257.836, 250.676, 237.466, 248.142, 142.511, 116.839, 
    66.76, 23.942, NA, 0, 0, 0, 27.992, 78.208, 306.763, 361.578, 
    303.356, 248.948, 193.574, 184.743, 104.518, 76.36, 44.371, 
    15.609, NA, 0, 49.073, 356.27, 546.462, 764.171, 822.19, 
    910.403, 818.073, 687.538, 601.246, 598.949, 301.036, 265.579, 
    129.278, 55.892, 11.525, 0, 60.115, 316.231, 496.366, 764.952, 
    1086.271, 982.368, 839.902, 757.569, 622.151, 733.912, 314.365, 
    242.839, 138.138, 67.617, 15.515, 0, 0, 51.362, 135.969, 
    253.814, 353.437, 346.998, 314.292, 385.864, 516.589, 627.003, 
    263.782, 274.407, 127.667, 45.013, NA, 0, 0, 0, 59.682, 237.216, 
    380.224, 528.946, 523.512, 446.714, 417.835, 352.487, 199.18, 
    195.568, 99.99, 39.81, NA), drug = c("T", "T", "T", "T", 
    "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "T", "T", "T", "T", 
    "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", 
    "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", 
    "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R")), row.names = c(NA, -128L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

The code I use for 'average' plot is the following:
data <-
  Totalplot |>   
  group_by(drug, time) |>
  summarise(conc = mean(conc, na.rm = TRUE))   
plot <-
  ggplot(
    data = data, aes(x = time, y = conc, color = drug)) +
  geom_point(
    aes(
      group = interaction(drug, time)), alpha = 0.5, shape = 2, position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0)) +
  geom_line(data = data, linewidth = 0.5) +
  xlab('Time, h') + 
  ylab('Drug X plasma conc. ng/ml') +
  labs(title = 'Mean plasma concentration') +
  theme_bw()      


Use lapply:
subjectsIDs <- unique(Totalplot$subj)
plots <- lapply(subjectIDs, function(x) {
  Totalplot %>% filter(subj == x) %>%
    ggplot(
      aes(x = time, y = conc, color = drug)) +
    geom_point(
      aes(
        group = interaction(drug, time)), alpha = 0.5, shape = 2, position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0)) +
    geom_line(linewidth = 0.5) +
    xlab('Time, h') + 
    ylab('Drug X plasma conc. ng/ml') +
    labs(title = paste('Subject', x, 'plasma concentration')) +
    theme_bw()
})

Not sure if this is what you mean by assigning a subject ID to each plot, but you can name each element of the list of plots:
names(plots) <- subjectIDs

Letting you access each plot like this:
plots[["1"]]


If you don't want plots for subjects without data at 48 hours to have that extra space to the right, filter out the NAs:
subjectsIDs <- unique(Totalplot$subj)
plots <- lapply(subjectsIDs, function(x) {
  Totalplot %>% filter(subj == x, !is.na(conc)) %>%
    ggplot(
      aes(x = time, y = conc, color = drug)) +
    geom_point(
      aes(
        group = interaction(drug, time)), alpha = 0.5, shape = 2, position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0)) +
    geom_line(linewidth = 0.5) +
    xlab('Time, h') + 
    ylab('Drug X plasma conc. ng/ml') +
    labs(title = paste('Subject', x, 'plasma concentration')) +
    theme_bw()
})
names(plots) <- subjectsIDs
plots[["1"]]



Alternatively, if you want all the plots arranged in a grid:
plot <- Totalplot %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(x = time, y = conc, color = drug)) +
  geom_point(
    aes(
      group = interaction(drug, time)), alpha = 0.5, shape = 2, position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 0.5) +
  xlab('Time, h') + 
  ylab('Drug X plasma conc. ng/ml') +
  labs(title = 'Plasma concentration by subject') +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(subj))
plot



Ah you beat me to it with facet_wrap :). Only suggestion is you can use the formula style for setting the facet: facet_wrap(~ subj)

@gabagool For real? I've been using facets = vars(...) for years - can't believe I never knew that, thanks!

welp it turns out formula style is apparently the old style. From the docs: For compatibility with the classic interface, can also be a formula or character vector. Use either a one sided formula, ~a + b, or a character vector, c("a", "b").

@Eonema All your suggestions are very useful for me, thank you for helping with the code.

In continuation of this topic I`m wondering how to change legend title..?(say, from drug to Treatment). I tried +scale_fill_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title = 'Treatment'))  but no changes appeared. Also with labs(), scale_* , guides() commands. Have some idea how to do it?

@RomanMaksvytis Use scale_color_discrete instead of scale_fill_discrete, because you've assigned drug to the color aesthetic, not the fill aesthetic.
